# Python - Add a value to an Excel's cell after all the existing values

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

For a personal project, I'm trying to get the month we're in, to put it into an Excel file (here called 'Countries_Data.xlsx') where other values are already.

I'd like that every time I launch the script, the month is added after all the value I have (here in the A column, named 'Month_Data'). In this column, the first value (here a month) I want to have will be on the 4th row (A4)

In order to do so, I've tried this little code, using datetime and openpyxl modules, with a *while* loup, unsuccessfully.

PS: I've attached the error messages at the end of my post (One of the errors stipulates that I call a deprecated function, but I don't know which other function I could use to make the same action)

'''

```
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl

mth=datetime.now().month,
file=openpyxl.load_workbook('Countries_Data.xlsx')
sheet=file.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
i=1
while sheet['A{}'.format(i)]!='':
    i+=1
sheet['A{}'.format(i)]=mth
```

Errors:

```
*File Directory*: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname]).
sheet=file.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "*File Directory*", line 8, in <module>
    while sheet['A{}'.format(i)]!=None:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 307, in __getitem__
    return self._get_cell(min_row, min_col)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 253, in _get_cell
    raise ValueError("Row numbers must be between 1 and 1048576")
ValueError: Row numbers must be between 1 and 1048576
```

'''

Comment: The error message tells you've gone too far: your condition will never be met so you keep adding cells until you have too many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alistair

It tells you how to refer to the sheet in the message - wb[*sheet_name*], also openpyxl has a built-in way to find the last row with data - max_row.

See if this works for you.

```
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl

mth = datetime.now().month

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Countries_Data.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet2']
nextrow = sheet.max_row + 1

sheet[f'A{nextrow}'] = mth

wb.save('Countries_Data.xlsx')
wb.close()
```